# How to get tweets about Indian congress not other congress

Tags: twitter, hashtag, tweets

I am using twitter api to get some tweets. However I realized that for #congress I also get tweets about the congress in US. How do I restrict it to Indian congress only? I can limit it based on the location, but then I lose out on tweets about Indian congress by people living in the US. Also if I search for Indian National Congress or INC it reduces the no of tweets as most of the people just say congress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion might be to use different search criteria, like names of specific Indian politicians. Another might be to look at tweets in Hindi. I imagine there is a rich corpus of tweets in Hindi that will give you what you want. Also, there may be another hashtag to use as a filter.

Hope this helps.